# Regex negative lookahead is not working properly

Tags: regex

I have the following javascript code

```js
var d = '<some string 2>';
var a = ...;
var b = '<some string 1>';
.
.
.
var c = b.map.....
```

To find the closest string declaration to c, I was using something like this:

```
var \w+ = '(.*?)';(?:(?!var \w+ = '(.*?)';.*?var c = \w+\.map)).*?var c = \w+\.map
```

I am using negative lookahead to not match a declaration if there is another declaration ahead that matches. However, the result I am getting is still <some string 2>. Could someone please explain me what causes that to happen?

Comment: What should the desired output look like ?

Comment: Expected output should be <some string 1>. I am trying to get the closest string declaration to c. Since b is closest, I want the value of b there.

Comment: Sorry, the question is still unclear to /me. but luckily for you I am pretty new to regular expression too...   (But I do not know if that has anything to do with the description of the problem)

Comment: There are two string declarations: var b and var d. I want to match the one that is closest to var c = \w+\.map, which will be b.

Comment: You can also match the newlines, but matching javascript code like this can be very brittle. https://regex101.com/r/UBIe58/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The are more ways to match a string in JavaScript, and even more ways to break the pattern as this is very very brittle.

For the example data in the question, using a negative lookahead to assert that the next line does not start with the `.map` part or a string:

```php
^var\s+\w\s*=\s*(["'`])(.*?)\1;\n(?:(?!var\s+\w+\s*=\s*(?:\w+\.map\b|(["'`]).*?\3);\n).*\n)*var\s+\w+\s*=\s*\w\.map\b
```

- `^` Start of string
- `var\s+\w\s*=\s*` Match a possible `var` format and the equals sign
- `` (["'`]) `` Capture group 1, match one of `"` `'` or `` ` ``
- `(.*?)` Capture **group 2** capture the data that you want to find
- `\1;\n` A back reference to match up the quote in group 1
- `(?:` Non capture group, to repeat as a whole

  - `(?!` Negative lookahead, assert what is directly to the right is not

    - `var\s+\w+\s*=\s*` Match a `var` part with `=`
    - `(?:` Non capture group for the alternation `|`

      - `\w+\.map\b` Match the `.map` part
      - `|` Or
      - `` (["'`]).*?\3 `` Capture group 3 to match one of the quotes with a back reference to match it up
    - `)` Close non capture group
    - `;\n` Match `;` and a newline
  - `)` Close lookahead
  - `.*\n` Match the whole line and a newline
- `)*` Close non capture group and optionally repeat to match all lines
- `var\s+\w+\s*=\s*\w\.map\b` Match the line with `.map`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CFW5n7/1)

```js
const regex = /^var\s+\w\s*=\s*(["'`])(.*?)\1;\n(?:(?!var\s+\w+\s*=\s*(?:\w+\.map\b|(["'`]).*?\3);\n).*\n)*var\s+\w+\s*=\s*\w\.map\b/m;
const str = `var d = '<some string 2>';
var a = ...;
var b = '<some string 1>';
.
.
.
var c = b.map.....`;

const m = str.match(regex);
if (m) {
  console.log(m[2]);
}
```